# How realistic is the term "offer visa sponsorship" in a job ad?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

As far as I know, a person only needs visa sponsorship if he/she does not have a working visa for the particular country. Now there are plenty of jobs with title saying "offer visa sponsorship" although I have heard them employer usually are reluctant to go through the visa process for foreign candidates.

Does it implies that the company welcome candidates with no working visa? I assume a foreign candidate would be the last choice for an employer.

Comment: What would the companies gain by posting "offer visa sponsorship" if they are reluctant to hire foreign candidates?

Comment: Is your question of general matter or do you have a personal intend behind it ? Like "I saw this in a job ad I was interested in and I don't have a visa for country X, can I get employed without a visa if the company says so ?"

Comment: @Kozaky: Your comment looks like a decent answer :-). Care to convert it?

Comment: Impossible to answer and even if it was you're also forgetting about the fact that you can't distinguish between companies looking to hire cheap labour from newly industrialized countries and those who expanded their search to include other developed markets because they can't fill a position. Both are typically happy to sponsor if they find a candidate that matches their needs.

Comment: @sleske I was initially reluctant to in case any further details about specific countries and their legalities came up, but have done so.

Answer (score 2):

It will usually mean more money spent and paperwork for the company, but they're saying if you are worth it to them, they will help you relocate.

They are emphasising that they won't turn you down purely because you're not a local citizen.